# Symfony 2.5 server returns 500 status

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

When I'm doing a request into API that I've written using Symfony 2.5. I'm sending form data using POST method and in the controller I'm doing

```
$params = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
```

and if I do

```
var_dump($params);
```

I can see everything in console If I'm doing

```
console.log(data)
```

But If I try just do something like this:

```
array_keys($params)
```

Server returns me a 500 status code and error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://host.loc/app_dev.php/posts. Invalid HTTP status code 500
```

Comment: Have you checked your error log? There could be messages in both `app/logs/dev.log` and in your webserver's error log

Answer (score 0):

You will always get 500 Error if something went completely wrong.

e.g. even use dump() in twig - which is not allowed in production

1) try the same page in /app_dev.php/[page]
- enable debug, this should give you alot of info about the error

2) look at the correct log file /app/logs/ as mentioned above

I guess you calling getContent() on a null Object ;-)

Comment: I don't use Twig, I'm using angular. But it  doesn't matter. When I'm doing var_dump($params); it returns me an array of my params but after that if I do array_keys($params) in return an error. In dev.log file I found this 

Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in

But I'm just doing this after var_dump($params)

It seems my params have disappeared

Comment: does var_dump indeed show that $params is an array ()? are you sure you dont have $param in array_keys() instead of $params ?

Comment: I'm sure)
var_dump($params);
        array_keys($params);

Comment: Before var_dump I'm doing this

$params = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

Comment: I have no idea why array_keys() takes null value, because in sting above var_dump takes $params without any errors.

Comment: what happens if you var_dump AFTER array_keys()

Comment: ( i know it doesnt get call but still same error ? try out with a simple array, or put the output of your var_dump here)

Comment: array(2) {
  ["nick"]=>
  string(6) "Berdin"
  ["pass"]=>
  string(8) "password"
}

Comment: But is still not works. If I do var_dump after array_keys it returns an  error and I see in logs that null parameter given into array_keys, but how it can be possible? Maybe I should reinstall my php5?

Comment: very strange last Test what happens with $a=array("a" =>"Alf","b"=>"Berta");var_dump(array_keys($a));

Comment: It works but my code doesn't want to work. When I'm doing $content = $request->getContent();
        $param = json_decode($content, true); I thin something wrong after json_decode . I reinstalled my PHP but it didn't help. I'm going to write to Symfony support , maybe there is some mistake in the framework.